# How to prevent dropping an item from a particular view?

Tags: javascript, datatable, drag-and-drop, webix

I have several lists and a Webix datatable. According to the use case, the datatable should be able to receive items from the list, but not its items cannot be dropped to these lists.

For now, the datatable config looks like:

```
{ 
  view:"datatable", 
  columns:[
    { id:"id" },
    { id:"value", width:200 },
    { id:"summary", fillspace:true },
    { 
      id: "delete", header:" ",
      template: "<icon class='webix_button webix_icon fa-trash delete'></icon>"          
    }
  ],       
  drag:true, // not enough
  data:initialData,
  onClick:{
    delete: function(ev, id){
      this.remove(id); 
    }
  }  
},
```

[Code snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/dc8139ae)

Is there a way to prevent dropping from a particular view?? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict **dropping from or in** a particular by writing customized function for *onBeforeDrag/Drop or onAfterDrag/Drop* depending upon your requirements.
Here is a small example where i am testing if the view id is d2 then the drop will not be done due to **return false**

```
on:{
     onBeforeDrop : function(context, ev){
                  if($$("myDragView").getChildViews()[1].config.id == "d2")
                  {
                      return false;      //denies dropping if id == d2
                  }
                  return true;         
         } 
 }
```

For your case, I have prevented the drop amongst the list, hence, you can only drop to the datatable. Please check the snippet [here](http://webix.com/snippet/158477f1).

**NOTE:** ***getChildViews()*** returns an array (index starting from 0) of all the children of the calling component.